# Is $A$ a compact operator or not?

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

Let $ A\colon L_1[0,1] \to C[0,1] $

$$ Af(t) = \int_0^t f(s)ds,\quad f \in L_1[0,1] $$

Is $A$ a compact operator or not?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the proposed duplicate. Both the domain and the codomain are different. And the conclusion as well.

Comment: @julien Whoops.

Comment: A related [problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182641/compact-operators-and-uniform-convergence).

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal These are not Hilbert spaces. And the operator is not compact. This is quite unrelated.

Comment: @julien: I know there is no Hilbert spaces! But there is the related definition of a compact operator "they map bounded sequences in X to sequences in Y with convergent subsequences" which has been used the answer as you see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it isn't.

The image of any bounded sequence under a compact operator must have a norm-convergent subsequence.

Consider the functions $f_n=n\chi_{[0,1/n]}$, $n=1,2,\ldots$.  Each $f_n$ has $L_1$-norm one, but the sequence $(Af_n)$ has no subsequence which converges in $C[0,1]$.

To see this, note $f_n$ is the continuous function whose graph consists of the straight line segments connecting the points $(0,0)$, $(1/n,1)$, and $(1,1)$. Given any $n$, it is easy to see that there is an $M$ so that $\Vert Af_n-Af_m\Vert_{\infty}>1/2$ for all $m\ge M$.

Comment: In your coment "To see this, note $f_n$ is the continuous function..." you mean "To see this, note $Af_n$ is the continuous function..." right?

Comment: @OEmpaladordeCabras Yes, thanks for pointing out the typo.