# Integral continuity. Is $L:C([0,1]) \rightarrow C([0,1])$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

$M:[0,1]\times[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous.
Let $L:C([0,1]) \rightarrow C([0,1])$ be defined by
$$L(f)(t) = \int_{0}^{1}M(t,s)f(s) ds$$
and $C([0,1])$ has the norm $||f||_{\infty} = \sup\{|f(x)| \text{  such that } x \in [0,1]\}$,

$f \in C([0,1])$.

**Questions:**

1)Is $L:C([0,1]) \rightarrow C([0,1])$ continuous?

2)Show that $||L|| \le \sup \{\int_{0}^{1} | M(t,s)|\text{  }ds \text{  } | t \in[0,1]\}$

---

1)
The first idea that came to my mind is to prove that $L$ is differentiable which automatically proves continuity. $M$ is continuous ,therefore Riemann differentiable.The question is if the integral is differentiable + 
 I don't quite understand how $f$ and the norm of $C$ matters in this question.
(infinite norm is just the maximal function value on $[0,1]$ (?))

2)
As of two I would appreciate any help. Maybe it will follow from 1)

**Update:**
[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889182/show-t-c0-1-rightarrow-c0-1-is-compact?rq=1) looks familiar...

Comment: You have to be careful. Now $L: C([0,1])\to C([0,1])$ is a mapping between Banach space, do you really want to show that $L$ is differntiable?

Comment: What do you know about continuity of a linear map between normed linear spaces? If you can explain that, then perhaps someone here can help you better.

Comment: I just know that linear map is continuous iff it's bounded by a linear operator

Comment: Since $L$ is a linear operator, you have to show simply 2), and you will get that $L$ is automatically continuous.