# $T(\varphi_k) = \frac{1}{k}\varphi_{k+1}$ is compact but has no eigenvector

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

I have some questions about the following exercise (Stein's Real Analysis / Measure Theory)

> **Exercise $33$**
> Let $\mathcal H$ be a Hilbert space with **'basis'** $\{\varphi_k\}_k$. Verify that the operator $T$ defined by
>
> $$T(\varphi_k) = \frac{1}{k}\varphi_{k+1}$$
>
> is compact, but has no eigenvector.

**1st**

I think the **'basis'** should be '**orthonormal**' to solve the compactness. As written in this [page](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1034251/1118138), we have to define a compact operator (finite rank) $T_n$, and obtain an inequality $\Vert (T-T_n)x \Vert ^2 \le \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\Vert x \Vert ^2$ to induce $\Vert T-T_n \Vert \le \frac{1}{n+1}$. But this process is estimated that the basis has to be **orthonormal**, which is not written in the exercise. Can I regard the text 'basis' in the exercise as an omitted one of '**orthonormal**' basis? Or, is there any other way to show the compactness without the orthonormality?

**2nd**

I'd like to check my approach regarding the existence of eigenvector.

Let $f$ be an eigenvector of $\mathcal H$ : $T(f) = \lambda f$ where $f = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k \varphi_k$, $a_k \in \mathbb C$.

$T(f) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k T(\varphi_k) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k \frac{1}{k}\varphi_{k+1}$, which is equal to $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\lambda a_k \varphi_k$

Then, $\lambda a_1 \varphi_1 + \lambda a_2 \varphi_2 + \lambda a_3 \varphi_3 + ... = 0\varphi_1 + a_1\frac{1}{1}\varphi_2 + a_2\frac{1}{2}\varphi_3 + ...$

Inducively, we can obtain $a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = ... = 0$ (whether the $\lambda = 0$ or not).

So $f = 0$, which is a contradiction.

---

Any comments about this would be grateful.

Comment: Clean argument!